# Docker run hello-world failure: daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380

Tags: docker, containers, runtime-error, runtime, failed-installation

I have a unique problem running docker's hello-world
on Windows Server 2019, with Ubuntu's version
Ubuntu_2004.2020.424.0_x64. The run fails.

I have performed the standard install instructions for
Docker given on the Docker website, for Ubuntu.

The Docker service is running, yet the software
cannot perform Docker's standard test of hello-world.

Are there unique settings which can aid in this problem?

## The commands used are below:

docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
2db29710123e: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:2498fce14358aa50ead0cc6c19990fc6ff866ce72aeb5546e1d59caac3d0d60f
Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:latest
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:722: waiting for init preliminary setup caused: EOF: unknown.

Comment: Please include the actual steps you performed, and output to show they were completed successfully, rather than saying you followed steps on a website. Also include the output of `docker info` and `docker version`.

Comment: Thank you, for your reply. I agree with your comment.  I will post the entire list commands of  I used, however, the Windows 2019 computer, I was using failed with a battery problem, shortly after I made the post.  Because of this temporary hardware problem. there will be a delay in finishing my  post.